# UML metamodel not found in createing Acceleo project

Tags: eclipse, acceleo

I am new in Acceleo. I use eclipse Mars. I want to getting start and learn with [this link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Getting_Started). when I want to create a new project and click add in the field of Metamodel URIs I didn't find UML Metamodel. what can I do?

Comment: Did you installed the UML2 eclipse plugin? This is the one which owns the UML2 metamodel and some UML2 related tools.

Comment: @VincentAranega No, I did'nt install it. Thanks a lot. My problem solved.

Comment: @Vincent Aranega you can write your answer.

Comment: I'll write it later. I will also add some links about acceleo if you want.

Comment: @Vincent Aranega It's very nice of you to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UML metamodel is only accessible by Acceleo if it is registered in the global EMF `ERegistry`. It means that it must be either loaded as an EMF plugin in your Eclipse environment or manually added to the global registry of your running Eclipse instance.

For UML, it is quite simple, you need to install the UML2 plugin. It provides the UML metamodel java code and `.ecore` as well as many tools around UML.

Also, if you want more details about Acceleo syntax, you can use these links:

#### Language Reference

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.acceleo.doc/pages/reference/language.html

#### Operations

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/OCL_Operations_Reference
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Acceleo_Operations_Reference

#### Text production rules

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Text_Production_Rules

And a small tutorial I wrote (only part 1 at the moment):

http://blog.genmymodel.com/build-your-own-php-generator-from-uml-using-acceleo-part-1.html